# Detecting overlapping polygon2D colliders in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to program an isometric building placement script. Each building has a PolygonCollider2D component on it with a trigger. When placing a new building, I'm trying to check if the PolygonCollider2D of the placed building overlaps with anything else (to check if placement is valid). My code is as follows:

Adjust the points of the new placed building collider based on the mouse position

```cs
Vector2[] points = polygonCollider2D.points;
points.SetValue(polygonCollider2D.points[0] + (Vector2)mousePosition, 0);
points.SetValue(polygonCollider2D.points[1] + (Vector2)mousePosition, 1);
points.SetValue(polygonCollider2D.points[2] + (Vector2)mousePosition, 2);
points.SetValue(polygonCollider2D.points[3] + (Vector2)mousePosition, 3);
polygonCollider2D.points = points;
```

**Set up contact filter:**

```cs
ContactFilter2D contactFilter2D = new ContactFilter2D();
contactFilter2D.useTriggers = true;
contactFilter2D.SetLayerMask(polygonCollider2D.gameObject.layer);
```

**Check for collisions**

```cs
List<Collider2D> list = new List<Collider2D>();
Debug.Log(polygonCollider2D.OverlapCollider(contactFilter2D, list));
```

However if there is already a building there, it still does not register an overlap.
What am I missing / doing wrong ?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code which sets the polygon collider points seems to be the issue here. If that code runs multiple times, it will repeatedly offset the collider further and further away from its original position. You probably don't want to be changing the actual collider; usually you should move object which has the collider. So you would replace those lines with something like this:

```
gameObject.transform.position = mousePosition;
```

Comment: The way I have it set, is that the actual object is not created at the time of the validation. I grab the collider of the object from the prefab, and I'm attempting to validate the placement. If the placement is valid only then will the object be placed.

I should mention that the code to set the polygon collider points is only ran when the mouse button is clicked and not multiple times.

Comment: If it runs whenever there is a mouse click, that means it is running multiple times over the life of the prefab. Unless you are making a copy of the PolygonCollider2D component, this will repeatedly shift the collider in the prefab, since edits to a prefab will be permanent, even if applied during run mode.